# Visual Studio 2013 crashes on debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, crash

2 wierd behaviors:
1. VS2013 crashes in specific code line on debug (whether it has a breakpoint or not)
2. When it's reopened, all of the deleted breakpoints 'return'!

It happens again and again.

Comment: delete all the generated binaries, the issue is sounding more like a stale PDB debug file that was generated. What kind of project was this?

Comment: Clean and rebuild solution.  If that does not help, reinstall VS.